# How can we find the area of quadrilateral with coordinates as points-$A(1,0,1),B(1,3,4),C(0,2,2),D(3,2,5)$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

This question was asked in a quiz.I've proved that these points are coplanar,all lying in $x+y-z=0$.I tried it by using the formula for the area of tringles in coordinate geometry(taking points $A,B,C$ & points $A,B,D$),but arranging the points in a correct manner so that there is no  area common to both the triangles seems cumbersome.

Is there any general formula for the computation of area of the given quadrilateral?

> **EDIT:After H.H.Rugh's answer**

- $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}=\begin{vmatrix}
          i & j & k \\
          1 & 0 & 1 \\
          1 & 3 & 4 \\
          \end{vmatrix}
  =i(0-3)-j(4-1)+k(3-0)=-3i-3j+3k$
- $\vec{b} \times \vec{c}=\begin{vmatrix}
          i & j & k \\
          1 & 3 & 4 \\
          0 & 2 & 2 \\
          \end{vmatrix}
  =i(6-8)-j(2-0)+k(2-0)=-2i-2j+2k$
- $\vec{c} \times \vec{d}=\begin{vmatrix}
          i & j & k \\
          0 & 2 & 2 \\
          3 & 2 & 5 \\
          \end{vmatrix}
  =i(10-4)-j(0-6)+k(0-6)=6i+6j-6k$
- $\vec{d} \times \vec{a}=\begin{vmatrix}
          i & j & k \\
          3 & 2 & 5 \\
          1 & 0 & 1 \\
          \end{vmatrix}
  =i(2-0)-j(3-5)+k(0-2)=2i+2j-2k$

Putting above values in,$ \vec{S} = \frac12 \left( \vec{a}\times \vec{b}+ \vec{b}\times \vec{c} +\vec{c}\times \vec{d} +\vec{d}\times \vec{a}\right) $,we get $\vec{S}=3i+3j-3k \implies \vert \vec{S} \vert=\frac12 \vert 3i+3j-3k \vert=\frac32 \sqrt 3$.

**But,its correct answer is $\frac92 \sqrt 3$**

Comment: It seems that ABCD is not a genuine quadrilateral.  AD and BC are crossing which makes the formula more complicated. You will have to compute the crossing point P and then the areas of ABP and PDC. I don't know if there is a general formula avoiding the computation of P?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh:It is not that ABCD is a quadrilateral,here it is given that A,B,C,D are the coordnates of the corner points of quadrilateral.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh:I guess your formula works only when the coordinates of quadrilateral are given in a suitable order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may compute the signed area of $OAB$ by:
$$ \frac12 \vec{OA}\times \vec{OB} = \frac12 \vec{a}\times \vec{b}$$
In your case the order of points which produce a genuine quadrilatere is: $A,D,B,C$ (look e.g. at the (x,y) projection) so the formula is:
Now you simple add all the contributions by cyclically permuting $ADBC$:
$$ \vec{S} = \frac12 \left( \vec{a}\times \vec{d}+ \vec{d}\times \vec{b} +\vec{b}\times \vec{c} +\vec{c}\times \vec{a}\right) $$
Cancellation will occur for the part which is outside the quadrilateral.
The area is the length of $S$.

If you know that the points form a convex quadrilatere then you may add the absolute value of the areas of $ABC$ and $ABD$. Complications may arise, however, when it is not convex.

Comment: :please help me in pointing my mistake.

Comment: :Now it is working,but my question is how we will be sure that triangles $ABC$ & $ABD$ do not have any area in common?Is there any trick?(lols)

Comment: If the quadrilatere is convex then that does not happen. But if it is not convex you will have problems. If e.g. $A$ is in the interior of $BCD$ then the area of $ABCD$ is in fact $|BCD|-|BAD|$ and it is different from the area of $BACD$. It is possible to check for non-convexity but a bit lengthy...

Comment: :I got it.Thanks for having a nice discussion.

Comment: You're welcome. As a side remark, my formula is well-known in 2 dimensions (Gauss' area or shoelace formula). But funny to get it in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Find vectors $\vec{AB},\vec{BC},\vec{CD},\vec{DA}$ & then compute 
$\frac12$ $\vert\vec{AB}\times \vec{BC} + \vec{CD}\times \vec{DA}\vert$.

Comment: @jnyan:How you are so sure that triangeles $ABC$ & $CAD$ do not have any area in common?

Comment: actually, I made a mistake. it should be 1/2 (AD X DB  + BC X CA). Because D, C are on opposite sides of AB. So A,B will be opposite vertices. And since sides of Quadrilateral are not mentioned, you can choose for maximum area, by choosing sides which do not overlap.